# How to use regex to match multiple paragraphs?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to process the html from a webpage and extract the paragraphs that match my criteria. The flavor of regex is PHP.

This is the sample webpage HTML:

```
<div class="special">
    <p>Some interesting text I would like to extract</p>
    <p>More interesting text I would like to extract</p>
    <p>Even more interesting text I would like to extract</p>
</div>
```

The regex looks between the `<div class="special">` and `</div>` tags and puts everything into a capture group or variable for reference in the next step. This next step is what I am having trouble with. I cannot for the life of me write a regex that captures each paragraph of text between `<p>` and `</p>`.

I have tried `/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/s` which returns:

```
<p>Some interesting text I would like to extract</p>
<p>More interesting text I would like to extract</p>
<p>Even more interesting text I would like to extract</p>
```

I would like each paragraph to be returned **individually** as items in an array. The non greedy `?` does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use an html parser (eg the DOM module in PHP) rather than regular expressions for this.

Comment: This regexp works in my editor:  `<p>(.+?)</p>`  Note that you have forward slashes and spaces in your regexp, which don't make sense to me.

Comment: The spaces are to bypass Stackoverflow's text formatting quirks. I don't know how to type the paragraph tag and have it appear without spaces.

Comment: Use a backtick character for inline code, not a single quote.

Comment: seems to work :- http://ideone.com/4jeQjz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So stupid! The regex works perfectly. All the regexs work perfectly. The problem was with the inputs. 
The input HTML file I was processing had the following structure which made the regex not work.

```
<p>Some interesting text I would like to extract
<p>More interesting text I would like to extract
<p>Even more interesting text I would like to extract</p></p></p>
```

I used var_dump(htmlfile.html) to see the HTML page I was getting but my browser processed it so I was not getting the raw data. I was able to get the raw data and find my mistake by using:

```
include 'filename.php'; 
file_put_contents('filename.php', $data);
```

Now I know to not trust my browser to return raw data ever again!

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape your slash for the p tag.

So it's going to be

```
/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/s
```

Comment: I have tried '/(?<=<p>).+(?=<\/p>)/smU' with preg_match_all and it still does not give me the desired result. Could it be that my PHP is broken? 
Link to show that it works: https://regex101.com/r/nP6nI2/1

Comment: That expression is using lookbehind and lookahead right?  The central regexp is `.+` which is greedy.  Maybe try non-greedy there: `/(?<=<p>).+?(?=<\/p>)/smU`